# JQuery animation: Is it possible to change speed during the animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I want to move a div down a page, and I want it to slow down as it reaches the target.

I tried using call back with recursive func but it doesn’t look smooth:

```
function MovePanel() {
    sidePanel.animate({
        "marginTop": newCurrTop
    }, moveSpeed, function () {
        MovePanel();
    });
}
```

Is it possible to slow down an JQuery animation?

If not what are the alternatives?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The animate method takes a 3rd param called "easing"; learn about it here:

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check this out: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/quick-tip-add-easing-to-your-animations

> Easing can really bring life to an
>   effect. Easing controls how an
>   animation progresses over time by
>   manipulating its acceleration.