# Jquery : Increase animation speed during animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

i am animating a div on click event what i want  is increase speed of animation after every 0.2 seconds this is what i'm doing now

```
 <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 animatediv' >
      <img src='images/camera.png' alt='camera'  class="camera">
      <p id='cameras' class='text-danger pull-right'>
      interested ? Read more
    </p>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#cameras').click(function(){
         $(".animatediv").animate({'position':'relative','left':'700px'}, 2000, function(){
            window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
        });
     });
});
```

now it animates whole div but i want i want to vary speed as mentioned above , Please help

Comment: Are you looking for easing functions? Something like this: http://easings.net/ may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery animate is used as .animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )

You can reduce duration (in milliseconds) to make it appear faster( which is 2000 is your case)

Reduce it to 500 or less. Or you can use 'fast'  in place of 2000

Answer (score 0):

Easings may help you to vary the speed during animation. Check out the link below for an example.

[JQuery animation: Is it possible to change speed during the animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382002/jquery-animation-is-it-possible-to-change-speed-during-the-animation)